# How to unhide the Breadcrumb on 2013

Tags: 2013, breadcrumb

I know this question has been asked but I have not found a solution that helped me.

How can I add the breadcrumb back to SharePoint 2013 on the Seattle master page?

I have tried removing the style tag and making the "Visible" equal true. But for some reason I am running into a problem. It even worked on our test site but there seems to be an issue on our production site. It almost seems like the .master page is not updating the changes made on the .html page.

Here is the code I changed.

```
 <div class="ms-breadcrumb-top">
                                <div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox">
                                    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">-->
                                    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:PopoutMenu
    Visible="true"
```

Comment: If I recall correctly you have to change two things in the master page to re-enable the breadcrumb. Also make sure you actually changed, checked in, and approved/published the master page in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do multiple things in order to get breadcrumb back.It is advisable not to do in seattle as it will effect everywhere.You can use custom masterpage in replace of seattle

Follow this link to get breadcrumb

http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: We would want the breadcrumb to show up on all sites, so would it be okay to do in Seattle in this case?

Comment: Yes in all system pages also?If it is so then you can.